# Python pandas pivot/stack operation

Tags: python, pandas

It seems a basic pivot operation. I want to do it in python pandas. My dataset looks like:

```
Date        weekno no_visitors_store1   no_visitors_store2 no_visitors_store3

2015/01/01    1            45                 34                  46
2015/01/02    1            40                 32                  100
2015/01/03    1            45                 30                  46
2015/01/04    1            45                 11                  10
```

I want to pivot in such a way so that I want to transpose only last three columns so that I can have store as a column and their coreesponding numbers.

```
Date          weekno    store  no_of_vistors     
2015/01/01    1         store1  45
2015/01/01    1         store2  34
2015/01/01    1         store3  46
2015/01/02    1         store1  40  
2015/01/02    1         store2  32  
2015/01/02    1         store3  100
```

There is a stack option to the do the above task. But not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) first column names and then use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('no_visitors_','')
print(pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Date','weekno'], value_name='no_of_vistors', var_name='store'))
          Date  weekno   store  no_of_vistors
0   2015/01/01       1  store1             45
1   2015/01/02       1  store1             40
2   2015/01/03       1  store1             45
3   2015/01/04       1  store1             45
4   2015/01/01       1  store2             34
5   2015/01/02       1  store2             32
6   2015/01/03       1  store2             30
7   2015/01/04       1  store2             11
8   2015/01/01       1  store3             46
9   2015/01/02       1  store3            100
10  2015/01/03       1  store3             46
11  2015/01/04       1  store3             10
```

Another solution with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```
print(df.set_index(['Date','weekno'])
        .stack().reset_index(name='no_of_vistors')
        .rename(columns={'level_2':'store'}))

          Date  weekno   store  no_of_vistors
0   2015/01/01       1  store1             45
1   2015/01/01       1  store2             34
2   2015/01/01       1  store3             46
3   2015/01/02       1  store1             40
4   2015/01/02       1  store2             32
5   2015/01/02       1  store3            100
6   2015/01/03       1  store1             45
7   2015/01/03       1  store2             30
8   2015/01/03       1  store3             46
9   2015/01/04       1  store1             45
10  2015/01/04       1  store2             11
11  2015/01/04       1  store3             10
```

Solution with `lreshape`, but column `store` is missing:

```
cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'no_visitors' in col]
print(pd.lreshape(df, {'no_of_vistors':cols}))
          Date  weekno  no_of_vistors
0   2015/01/01       1             45
1   2015/01/02       1             40
2   2015/01/03       1             45
3   2015/01/04       1             45
4   2015/01/01       1             34
5   2015/01/02       1             32
6   2015/01/03       1             30
7   2015/01/04       1             11
8   2015/01/01       1             46
9   2015/01/02       1            100
10  2015/01/03       1             46
11  2015/01/04       1             10
```

Comment: @jezreal Thank you very much for your articulate response. Use of melt function is great. So one thing-if in real I have 25 stores-do I have to hard code each of them in lreshape statement?. Can I use something like ['no_visitors_store1'-- 'no_visitors_store2']

Comment: No, you canuse list comprehension like `cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'no_visitors' in col]`

Comment: and then `print(pd.lreshape(df, {'no_of_vistors':cols}))`, but I remove this solution, because store name are missing.

Comment: OK....but in your very last edit...the output seems little incorrect. Can you please revert to your previous edit which used lreshape.

Comment: Do you think different order?

Comment: There were some stupid typos, now is looks much better. Please check solutions.